# Angular deployment without server - Error: SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History'

Tags: angular, deployment, angular-cli

I have a simple web application in Angular v5. This is a purely client-side application in the meaning of it doesn't use any server-side (this is a basic calculator application that load data from JSON file with some measurements and display to the user some analysis according to that JSON).

During development I've tested the application using the Angular-cli "serve", by running - `ng serve` command, and it works great.

Now I wont to bundle my app and start using it. I would like to run this app locally on my machine without any server. 
According to the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/deployment), to bundle the application to deployment, I should run the command: `ng build --prod --base-href=./`. There to flag `--prod` will deploy a *minified* and *uglified* version of the application. And the `--base-href=./` will set `<base href="./">` in the **index.html** to allow me loading the application files (all the ABC.bundles.js file) directly from the local machine.

Now, when I'm opening the `dist/index.html` file I can see that all the scripts have loaded, however, I have an error in the console:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute
>   'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL
>   'file:///C:/.../dist/' cannot be created in a document with origin
>   'null' and URL 'file:///C:/.../dist/index.html'.

How do I deploy/bundle my application to run locally, without a server?

Comment: @David, This is a completely different issue. Both issues have the same error in the console, but the scenario and the problem are completely different

Comment: It's not different, it's a limitation from the browser that you can't use history API on local files

Comment: Yes. Even if you're not using the History API directly, Angular is, behind the curtain.

Comment: But how is it related to Angular deployment?

Comment: That's the point, it is not. You need a webserver if you want to use history API, angular or not. Or try the workaround suggested in the link I posted

Comment: I didn't explicitly invoke `history-api`, what Angular component/service uses this API? maybe I can emit that component/service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using **angular-router** you need a server-side since the router is used to serve pages.

To solve these issue you have 2 choices:

1. Use some sort of light-weight server like NPM's [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) which allow you to run a server on a local machine from the command-line.
2. Drop the **angular-router** completely - Yes this is a bit extreme solution and I'm sure it will not be a valid solution to anybody with more than 2 pages in his application. But if you have a very very simple app with one page only and you don't need routing capabilities then this is a valid solution.

Comment: Just what I wanted to know. Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Try using `HashLocationStrategy`

https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy
https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy

In your module

```
imports [
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})
]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your routes configuration add;

`RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true});`

In your index.html do this;

`<!-- <base href="/"> -->
 <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>`

And then build with --base-href ./ e.g

`ng build --prod --base-href ./`

source https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13948

Answer (score 1):

i have also faced same issue and it was not working after deployment into server, i have added `HashLocationStrategy`.

https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy

https://angular.io/guide/router#hashlocationstrategy

for me page was not loading and throwing 404 page not found after requesting from Google.com

url --- http://techeducation.in

i have solved this after commenting or removing ...

`<base href="http://www.techeducation.in/" />` from index.html file of `dist` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Since Angular 13 despricated deployUrl. Cause trouble if you using CDN cache but your app running on different domain like heroku or something else.

here is the solution step by step:

1. delete deployUrl, no need to change it to baseHref, we keep it default
2. replace url to load it manually by replace-file.js:

```
const replace = require('replace-in-file');

const prefix = 'https://your-cdn.com/assets';

const action2options = {
  files: path.join(process.cwd(), '/dist/browser/index.html'),
  from: [/<script src="(.*?)"/g],
  to: [`<script src="${prefix}$1"`],
};


replace(action2options)
  .then(results => {
    // console.log('Replacement results:', results);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error occurred:', error);
  });
```

3. load the chunk using your assets CDN by add this line to main.ts (if use universal, add it to main.server.ts too:

```
// main.ts add it
// main.server.ts add it too if use universal
// https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22113#issuecomment-1004279867
declare var __webpack_public_path__: string;
__webpack_public_path__ = 'https://your-cdn.com/assets';
```

if you need change link by environment, use this to detect:

```
// angular.json => add to build -> scripts file

            {
                "input": "src/environments/replacer-build.js",
                "inject": false,
                "bundleName": "replacer-build.development"
              }
```

```
// update to production build too:
  "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
```

after that you can detect it in replace-file.js by this:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const files = fs.readdirSync(path.join(process.cwd(), '/dist/browser')).filter(file => {
  return file.match(/^replacer-build\.(development|production|staging)\.js$/);
});

let env = '';
let assetUrl = '';
if (files.length > 0) {
  const filename = files[0];
  if (filename.includes('development')) {
    env = 'development';
    assetUrl = 'http://localhost:4200/';
  else if (filename.includes('production')) {
    env = 'production';
    assetUrl = 'https://your-cdn.com/assets';
  }
}


console.log(`The current environment is ${env} and assetURL replace to:`, assetUrl);
```