# SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History':

Tags: angular, universal, server-side-rendering

I am facing this issue across all browsers. This comes up whenever I try to view my site in Google cache

`main.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://mydomainn.com/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://webcache.googleusercontent.com'`. The same problem lies with express google. http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fexpress.google.com%2Fstores&oq=cache%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fexpress.google.com%2Fstores&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.3999j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8.

My base href is `/`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular deployment without server - Error: SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365057/angular-deployment-without-server-error-securityerror-failed-to-execute-rep)

Comment: hi, did you solve your issue ?

Answer (score 16):

In your routes configuration add

```
 RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true});
```

In your index.html do this;

```
 <!-- <base href="/"> -->
 <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
```

And then build with --base-href ./ e.g

```
ng build --prod --base-href ./
```

source https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13948

Comment: Sir, you just saved my work day. Can't say if the answer solves the question though, as my issue was of different kind (index.html on a server and all application files on another)

Comment: I myself was trying to load an application from file system and ended up with this. 

Glad it was of whatever help it was to you.

Comment: Me ajudou muito. Thanks