# Angular 6, after ng build index.html gets errors in console

Tags: angular, angular-cli, console.log, ng-build, angular-builder

I'm facing a issue please help me to resolve this.
The issue is that when I do `ng build` in my CLI and go to the dist folder and run index.html file so the console get the errors of files path.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
polyfills.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
styles.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
scripts.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
vendor.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
/D:/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

Comment: @ZalnKhAn where you have to run your project locally or on server.?  you may add base url of project `i.e:- <base href="/vbhfd/">`.

Comment: The files must be in the document root of the webserver, otherwise you have to put the path in the "base" tag

Comment: Can you show me a demo like what I've to replace or put?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's only related to the path, simply use ***--base-href*** flag while building as follows -

```
ng build --prod --base-href ./
```

Now it generates the lines similar to the following in your ***index.html*** -

```
<base href="./">
<!-- Note the file names here -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.30458714a8af1a2e7153.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.db85ebdc34f3cf0f4d3f.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.e8fe6486441dc07e00c6.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.f9ea86a83ded92312d0f.js"></script>
```

That's it! It works everywhere, you just need to deploy the production build & you are ready to go!

> Also, please note that **if you are trying to run index.html right from your files, it won't work**. You'll need to place it on a http server (for example, [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) for local)

Comment: this issue come after that main.786282d324cee4d6299d.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///D:/angular/erp-core/dist/erp-core/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL 'file:///D:/angular/erp-core/dist/erp-core/index.html'.
Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'file:///D:/angular/erp-core/dist/erp-core/' cannot be created in a document with origin

Comment: I removed some basics tags from it because of comment box strength

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <base href="/">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-master-page></app-master-page>
<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="styles.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>

Comment: compare it with my updated anwer & please make sure that you have your production scripts with the same name you shown here.

Comment: Just run the command as above & don't change anything in index.html, that's it

Comment: for the `replaceState` error, configure your Router to use `useHash` as follows - `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })`

Comment: replaceState is still there after adding useHash

Comment: replaceState error is still there after adding useHash

Comment: refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365057/angular-deployment-without-server-error-securityerror-failed-to-execute-rep

Comment: what about images path?

Comment: refer this for relative paths - https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Comment: images path are perfect but it take the path of my drive

Comment: you can also set the base href value in the index.html file

Comment: It's working for me. Thank you so much buddy. I spent 2 days on google. Finally I managed to run my app.

Answer (score 1):

The default `base` for the `href` property is defined as `/` for angular cli projects. If you are building the project and accessing it by directly opening the index.html file, all the `.js` that the HTML wants to load will be loaded from the `'/' directory`.

For example, if you are using windows and your build is present in the `C:\users\xys\ng\dist\index.html` , and you have 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.js"></script>` in your HTML, the browser will look for the `.js` files in `C:\runtime.js`.

To solve it, you can either copy all your files to root of the drive (not suggested), or you can create a local server and then server the static files that server (preferred method).

Comment: For all the files referred in your HTML (example runtime.js in above case), if the source is not an absolute path, the browser will make request using the `value of base href='thisValue'`. when opening the HTML file, the `/` refers to the root directory (in case on *nix OS) and the root of the partition. in case of windows OS. So the request is made to ,say, `C:\runtime.js` which fails because the file does not exist