# SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History' error in Angular 6 when index.html call main.js from CDN

Tags: angular, angular6

I have an angular 6 application I have kept index.html in the web server and calling the bundles like main.js from cdn. When I do this I get the following error

> application error :  Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError:
>   Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object
>   with URL 'https://mywebsite-dev-cdn.mydomain.com/devorigin/webassets/'
>   cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://dev.mydomain.com' and
>   URL 'http://dev.mydomain.com/#'.

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365057/angular-deployment-without-server-error-securityerror-failed-to-execute-rep

Comment: please add a more complete example so we can help, a test project would be great, you can use https://stackblitz.com/