# Cant open html file after webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, react-router

I have compiled the project into the dist folder and want to launch the site from an html file. When using the server locale, everything works, but when you run html, an error is issued and the page does not load. What is the problem?

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': 
A history state object with URL 'file:///C:/404' cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL
```

Comment: does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63115145/domexception-failed-to-execute-replacestate-on-history-a-history-state-obj solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine, I replaced Browser Router with HashRouter